# How create subdomains in WordPress with almost the same content?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain

I need to make a site example.com in WordPress with a lot of content. And we have several users who need a subdomain to promote his referral site, like user1.example.com or user2.example.com.

Those subdomain must have almost the same content, except for one link. That link must change in every subdomain according to the subdomain itself. So it visitor came on user1.example.com that link must point to anotherdomain.com/USERID/.

Every subdomain-username have a separate USERID value correspondent.

So, I'm looking for to things:

1. Make subdomains with just one WP installation and the same content across all of them.
2. Make the referral link for each subdomain.

As far that I understand WPMU is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: you could get the url with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and then change the value with that.

Comment: Thank you! Yep, that could be for the link. But for the multi-subdomain what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Configure [wildcard subdomains](https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Wildcard_Subdomains) and then use

> $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

to parse the URL and create the link.
Please note that a user name might contain characters that aren't supported for subdomains.